# Enriching event with missing data

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, apache-kafka-streams

Say, you have to enrich an event by a mostly-static ID column, but half the corresponding data doesn't exist in your stream processors local store, but it does in your database. How would you solve this problem?

If I fetch for the missing data from database, what is the most sensible way to make this data available for future joins? Can I just produce into the topic with missing data?

Comment: Why aren't the records created with the ID to begin with? Consuming and doing a database lookup would be slower than the producer doing a lookup itself... Otherwise, are you using something like Debezium so you can convert the database into a stream you can join against to create events with the ID?

Comment: The events which I want to enrich are in similar format: {"user_id": 123, "ip": "0.0.0.0" ...}. I'd like to join on the "user_id" and add additional information to the event. Yes, I am using Debezium for CDC, but my problem is that a significant part of the user data doesn't exist in the local store for me to join on and they aren't getting any updates/deletes for Debezium to react on. That's because I didn't consider with click analysis, audit logging and various other things before building this application and now I'm trying to plug it in half way.

Comment: Do you need delete/update events? Debezium should snapshot the existing data, if you've allowed it to